# Dynamically Allocating Arrays Depending on User Input in C++

Tags: c++

im watching this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XAQzcJvOHk Dynamically Allocating Arrays Depending on User Input in C++

this is his code

```
1 int main()
2 {
3   int *pointer = nullptr;
4   
5   cout << "how many items u are gonna enter" << endl;
6   int input;
7   cin >> input;
8
9   pointer = new int[input];
10
11  int temp;
12
13  for (int counter = 0; counter < input; counter++) {
14      cout << "enter the item " << counter + 1 << endl;
15      cin >> temp;
16      *(pointer + counter) = temp;
17  }
18
19  cout << "the items you have entered are" << endl;
20  for (int counter = 0; counter < input; counter++) {
21      cout << counter + 1 << "  item is  " << *(pointer + counter) << endl;
22  }
23
24  delete[]pointer;
25
26  return 0;
27}
```

im stuck in line 16, i dont understand why is that, inside the (), the pointer variable and counter are added to each other

Comment: `*(pointer + counter)` is just another (and wackier) way to write `pointer[counter]`. It's not clear why the author chose to obfuscate matters in this way. In any case, it would have been better to use `std::vector<int>` in place of raw pointers and manual memory management.

Comment: In real code this should be `std::vector`.

Comment: And while I'm giving unsolicited coding advice: don't define `pointer` until it's used, i.e., `int *pointer = new int[input];`; and define `temp` inside the body of the `for` loop, since that's the only place it's used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pointer Arithmetic](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) is a good point where to start.

I'm going to try to explain you briefly how it works, but I strongly suggest you to integrate those concepts with a good book or internet references because they are very important for proper handling pointers.

A pointer (as you can imagine from the name) *points* a memory cell:

```
int* ptr = /*an address to the memory cell*/
```

Your memory is composed by sequentially cells, graphically:

```
Address|      Value
-------|------------
0x00   |    [#some value] 8 bit
0x01   |    [#some value] 8 bit
...    |    ...
0xN    |    [#some value] 8 bit
```

Just to make this example not so long, we can assume each cell contains 8 bits and a integer value is represented with exactly 32 bit (usually that is not true, and it depends on the machine architecture and compiler).

Then a `int` value is stored exactly in `4` cells. (We explicitly don't consider memory alignment).

So your pointer contains a memory location, the address in the memory which contains the value you've allocated (with the usage of dynamic memory).

For example:

```
int* ptr = 0x01
```

That means the variable ptr, stored somewhere in the memory, contains the address `0x01`. In the memory cell `0x01` there will be the integer value allocated dynamically.

But, since the value is an *integer* type, the data will take 4 cell in order to store the complete information. So the data will be "split" among the cell `0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04`.

The pointer will points the first memory location of the data, and the number of cell occupied is given by the type of pointer (in that case pointer `int` so the compiler knows the information starts from cell `0x01` and ends `0x04`).

A *variable pointer* can be evaluated in an arithmetic expression, such sums and differences.

Fo example:

```
ptr + 10
ptr - 10
```

Simply, the meaning of that expression is to access to memory address starting from the address stored in `ptr` and jumping `10` *int cells* forward or backward.

*Attention Note:* the expression *does not* mean to simply add the value to the address obtaining a new address.

Indeed, assuming `ptr = 0x01`, then the expression:

```
ptr + 10;
```

*does not mean* `0x01 + 10 = 0xa`!

Instead that means to jump 10 "block" of size equal to the type's size
pointed by the pointer itself.

That is, `0x01 + 10 * 4bytes`. 
Since `ptr` is a pointer to `int`, then `+10` means *"plus 10 block of integers"*, and, in this example, each `int` occupies 4 bytes (32 bit).

---

To conclude, the expression:

```
*(pointer + counter) = temp;
```

means to access to the address start from `pointer` and adding `#counter` block of `int`, then deference that address with the `operator*` and write in that address the value `temp`.

That notation can be easily simplify  with the `operator[]`:

```
pointer[counter] = temp;
```

where the meaning is exactly the same, but the notation is more readable, especially when you have to do with array.

Comment: It is odd to start with bits when the smallest addressable memory location is a 'byte'.

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
*(pointer + counter)
```

is just simple pointer arithmetic: we are adding `counter` (of type `int`) to the pointer address and then dereferencing it using `*`. **It is the same as     `pointer[counter]`**. After that, we are savig value of `temp` into that particular (dereferenced) location in memory.

Answer (score 1):

`*(pointer + counter)` is equivalent to `pointer[counter]` as has been pointed out, the reason it's equivalent is because pointer holds a memory address, when you add say 1 to the that memory address you are infact adding the size of whatever the data type that pointer is pointing to is, multiplied by 1.

If you have a primitive array

```
int arr[2] = {1,55};
```

`*arr` would give you 1 and `*(arr + 1)` would give you 55

Answer (score 1):

```
  *(pointer + counter) = temp;
```

is same as

```
pointer[counter] = temp;
```

The variable **pointer** contain the address of the first element of the array. 
Adding **counter** means selecting the address of **counter** away from starting address.

**counter** is simply an offset from **pointer**.